# Only getting admin user while fetching Users list Using WP Rest API

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am Using WordPress rest API with OAuth 1. When i try  to Fetch users list using wp-json/wp/v2/users/  I only get Admin user detail, not all users. I have completed OAuth authentication process ang got oauth token and secret. I have tried POST man as well REST client for Mozilla. Also i get "rest_cannot_create" when trying to create any POST or User.

Answer (score 0):

you will want to make sure that the users you want to appear have the "list_users" capability.

```
// get the the role object
$role_object = get_role( $role_name );

// add $cap capability to this role object
$role_object->add_cap( $capability_name );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/roles-and-capabilities/#adding-capabilities